# Alternative to using shebang

Tags: php, unix, shebang

I am trying to set up my system so that php can be run without including the shebang in every file. Is there an alternative to using `#!/usr/bin/php` in every php file I write?

Comment: Yes the alternative is running PHP scripts with `php filename.php` - is that "better" for your use case?

Comment: As Joni's comment suggests, I think [edit]ing the question to include more information on why you need this would be useful - what is the context where you want this to work, and what is the downside of shebang lines that you want to avoid?

Comment: are you using PHP CLI or PHP in browser? if the latter, this is never needed :S

Answer (score 1):

The shebang is only needed, if a PHP should be called directly by a shell/tool like any other shell script. Examples are functions `system()` or `exec*()` provided by many languages, including PHP.

If calling a command, the tools look for a shebang to decide, which interpreter is to call. This works for awk too:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { print "begin" }
```

The general idea is, to put commands e.g. in /usr/local/bin, make `chmod a+x` and use them like any other command without need, to select the needed interpreter manually.

### Conclusion

Shebang is not needed for web server files, that are never called as script by a shell or external tool.